# Makeshift Passive USB Charger 5V OVP

Tags: usb-device, circuit-protection, 5v, usb-c, over-voltage-protection

I was looking to protect my 5V device from 20V, since the charging port is Type-C, but used for USB 2.0 communication without any power delivery or bc. Expected to be charged with 1A-1.5A from the wall or USB 3.0 900ma (btw would I need any special IC to request 1A? I think not, but can be wrong)

The protection IC solutions always require power provided to that protection IC (3.3V or 5V). I wanted 0 consumption protection circuit, when charger is not plugged in.

So I quickly conjured up this little circuit on a napkin. Quickly threw it into circuitlab simulation thing, and it works (simulates) as intended. The load is disconnected as soon as Vin reaches 5.5-6V. So the thing works the way I want it to work.

Alternative solution would be to throw in some small linear regulator, tolerant to 20V+, which would power the protection IC (but I kinda feel proud that I invented this circuit in like 5 minutes).

I would like to have some feedback whether my circuit doesn't miss anything critical or makes sense at all. Of course I know I'll have to pick parts carefully in terms of leakage currents and threshold voltages etc. Or am I simply overcomplicating stuff and a tiny USB-powered LDO with protection IC is a no-brainer.

P.S. can't provide circuitlab link, the thing wants paid membership, if anyone wants to reproduce the circuit, I tweaked MOSFET thresholds down a little (default ones don't work at 5V I think). Caps optional.

[image]

Comment: But why is this necessary? If there is nothing to negotiate and request more than 5V, why would any charger give out more than 5V?

Comment: I've heard enough stories about Type-C chargers occasionally sending 20V (usually cheaper ones). There is a handful of chips that exists solely to protect 5V from up to 22V, I think they exist for a reason

Comment: You can treat it as a standalone problem of course. Just a 5V OVP circuit)

Comment: Why not use a buck-boost converter (3 volt to 40 volts in and 5 volts out)? BTW the R2C2 delay could cause a 10 ms+ overload conditions.

Comment: Yeah I should think about the caps. Probably remove that one. Why would I need a buck-boost? Minimum input is 5V, and the protection ICs are either 5V or 3.3V and consume only a tiny bit of a current. Again, expected input is 5V, 20V protection is just in rare case it ever sees 20V (probably never, but you never know). Buck-boost just for that seems like a huge waste of space and cost

Comment: You meant bypass protection by providing guaranteed 5V altogether? Still sounds like a waste of USB power, isn't it? As well as space and cost of components

Comment: Do you have a link to a story with 20V out of USB-C charger without any PD?

Comment: it wasn't about without PD. It was a cheap PD charger that was on 20V and didn't reset itself back to 5V if there was no negotiation for that ("feature" of the cheapest aliexpress pd chargers sometimes). But considering how much feedback I'm getting about it now, I probably worry too much and it's a rare exception, so I just clicked the answer below to mark the question as closed. (and I can't find source for that thing, was some time ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just try to protect against some "should never happen" case, a simpler solution may be to put a 5.6 - 6 V varistor like [this](https://www.digikey.ch/product-detail/de/littelfuse-inc/V8ZA2P/F3065-ND/1009661) across the power terminals.

The varistor can handle 250 A. I suggest to add also a fuse that would quickly disconnect the rogue power source. There are self-resetting fuses available on the market, say [hold 2 A, trip at 3.5](https://www.digikey.ch/product-detail/en/bel-fuse-inc/0ZRN0200FF1E/507-2387-ND/9468236).

The only problem I see with this solution is the quite wide range of the trigger voltages of the varistor. If the lower boundary is 6 V or about, the upper boundary may go as high as 11 V. It will trigger at 20 V anyway, but under some 8 V it may not.

Comment: Interesting idea. I have never used varistors, will do some research, read some datasheets, see if I can make anything fancy out of it. Even if I don't use it in the end (and maybe I will), still useful to know.

Comment: If you're going to use a fuse, so that the overvoltage condition can't last very long, then why not a 5.6 V zener, say a 5 watt part, in place of the varistor? Wouldn't that have a more predictable threshold voltage?